# Expresso-store: Display weight in grammes instead

Tags: expresso-store

How do I convert the weight of a product? Currently it's in kg, would like to display it in grammes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this within the template? If so, you could use a add-on like [MX Calculator](http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-calculator) to do the arithmetic.

```
{exp:mx_calc expression="{product_weight}*1000"}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Also works with dimensions. Sorry for the late reply, didn’t get a email notification.